# CGI not supported in a server...is it possible?

Tags: web-server, web-hosting, cgi

Goodmorning.
I'm very new to web developing.
I made a website whit a massive use of CGI, then I started to search for an host. Once I found my host I started to search for the configuration files of my server apache but I wasn't able to locate any httpd.conf or apache2.conf, then I contacted the host by live chat.
This is a short cut from the chat:

> Me: I would like to activate server-side includes for execute some
>   CGI on my web-pages, furthermore I would like to have a check to the
>   configuration file of the server but I cannot locate it
>
> Me: for server side includes I need to edit a file such access.conf
>   (at least this is the name on NCSA servers), but I cannot locate any configuration file.
>
> Answer: im sorry but CGI are not supported in our servers
>
> Me: but you do allow python, perl, ruby... scripting
>
> Answer: no im sorry

As I said I'm very new to this domain, I'm a bit confused because I always tough CGI are one of the basics of web developing. I understand it could be a stupid question but,
Is it possible that an host doesn't allow to run GCI on his servers?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is entirely possible. Actually CGI isn't that much used in web developing anymore. PHP and other languages are mainly used for web developing.